# Google Sheet - Formula which create a automatically table linked with management header need

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like automate a sheet template which will be used by others guys with specific datas.
In order to be more understandable, here after the link to my sheet example, for sure my official file are very, very more complexed:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UyW12WwG9sJUF0ZhnHGP9adgbY3xWUpj4kM9-ASN2WE/edit?usp=sharing

Due to these specific datas, I would like that each guy filled a header Management table (sheet Chart 1 range A4:F4 and sheet Chart 2 range A4:F4), and the formula build automatically the table in field I4 of the sheets Chart 1 & Chart 2.

I hope that my explanations are enough and clear, and I cross my finger that you will help me to find a solution which will be automated.

Thanks in advance. Regards.
Vincent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added solution to [sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UyW12WwG9sJUF0ZhnHGP9adgbY3xWUpj4kM9-ASN2WE/edit#gid=1747716799):

```
=LAMBDA(aix;MAP(INDEX(aix;;1);INDEX(aix;;2);INDEX(aix;;3);LAMBDA(ax;bx;cx;{ax\bx\cx\BYCOL(Datas!I:K;LAMBDA(ijk;SUMIFS(ijk;Datas!D:D;ax;Datas!E:E;bx;Datas!F:F;cx)))})))
(INDEX(SPLIT(FLATTEN(FLATTEN(FILTER(A5:A15; A5:A15<>"")&"|"&TRANSPOSE(FILTER(B5:B15; B5:B15<>"")))&"|"&TRANSPOSE(FILTER(C5:C15; C5:C15<>"")));"|")))
```

- 

[image]

Comment: Hello @rockinfreakshow,  fantastic it is perfectly that I need. But, when I copy/^paste your formula in Chart 2, the formula doesn't run, is it possible to arrange it in order that it will cover other configuration of management table ! Thanks again

Comment: Updated Chart 2 formula as well. Please do check it out.

Comment: This formula do the task, but I cannot use it for all my operational cases due I can have others number of inputs  in the  header management table.
For example, in the Chart3 sheet, I have inserted 2 new headers (Column A & B), but the header are empty to take into account other config tables. In this case, I haven't found the solution. Could you help me ? Also, could you please add the column headers inside of the formula as an array? Thanks for your appreciated support and help